# Uploading and downloading files on Onedrive via my website with PHP

Tags: php, web, storage, azure-storage, onedrive

I want people from my website to be able to upload a file to a specific onedrive folder on my onedrive account, let us call that folder "textdocuments". I also want people to be able to download a file from the specific "textdocuments" onedrive folder.

So basically my onedrive folder is going to act like a storage for files people upload on my website, which other people can then download. So far I have registered my app on Microsoft Azure, but I can for the love god not find anything on how to upload/download files via PHP.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) to create your application.

I create a basic sample for your reference: [PHP-MS-Graph](https://github.com/AI-EVO/PHP-MS-Graph). To run the sample, you need to have one active O365 account which can use OneDrive service.

And then follow [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)'s readme tutorial to:

1. [Register your application](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php#register-your-application)
2. Add necessary permissions, and grant admin consent for your tenant if needed. In this sample, you can add `Files.ReadWrite` delegated permission.
3. Use your own tenant id, application id, secret and account credentials in php.

---

## Upload.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$tenantId = 'your_tenanet_id, e4c9ab4e-****-****-****-230ba2a757fb';
$clientId = 'your_app_id_registered_in_portal, dc175b96-****-****-****-ea03e56da5e7';
$clientSecret = 'app_key_generated_in_portal, /pGggH************************Zr732';
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token';
$user_token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'your_user_id, jack@***.onmcirosoft.com', 
        'password' => 'your_password'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$user_accessToken = $user_token->access_token;

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($user_accessToken);

$graph->createRequest("PUT", "/me/drive/root/children/".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]."/content")
      ->upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

// Save to uploads folder on server
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

?>
```

## Download.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;

$target_dir = "downloads/";

$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$tenantId = 'your_tenanet_id, e4c9ab4e-****-****-****-230ba2a757fb';
$clientId = 'your_app_id_registered_in_portal, dc175b96-****-****-****-ea03e56da5e7';
$clientSecret = 'app_key_generated_in_portal, /pGggH************************Zr732';
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token';
$user_token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'your_user_id, jack@***.onmcirosoft.com', 
        'password' => 'your_password'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$user_accessToken = $user_token->access_token;

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($user_accessToken);

// Download to server
$target_dir = 'downloads/';
$graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/drive/root:/Capture.JPG:/content")
    ->download($target_dir.'Capture.JPG');

// Send download response to client
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($target_dir.'Capture.JPG').'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($target_dir.'Capture.JPG'));
flush(); 
readfile($target_dir.'Capture.JPG');
die();

?>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to make your solution to work, can you look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978877/onedrive-upload-msgraph-sdk-php-unable-to-open-file-stream-for-given-path-er Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me...