# Why does Microsoft Graph API deny my request to upload files to OneDrive from a PHP website?

Tags: php, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, guzzle

I have a website where my clients can view their invoices and upload design assets related to the invoice. I want to create a PHP form which uploads the files to OneDrive, instead of storing them on our web server.

I have followed the instructions in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249556/uploading-and-downloading-files-on-onedrive-via-my-website-with-php) to get started.

I have created the app in Microsoft Azure, and entered the appropriate Application (client) ID, Object ID, and Directory (tenant) ID. I am using a client secret to authorize the application, and submitting a POST request using my account's email and password to get the access token.

The relevant code for my upload form looks like this:

```php
if (isset($_FILES['uploads'])) {
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $tenantId = 'xxxxxx';
    $clientId = 'xxxxxx';
    $clientSecret = 'xxxxxx';
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token';
    $user_token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'username' => 'xxxxxx@companydomain.com', 
            'password' => 'xxxxxx'
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
    $user_accessToken = $user_token->access_token;

    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($user_accessToken);

    foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        try {
            $graph->createRequest(
                "PUT", "/drive/root:/Documents/".$_FILES['uploads']['name'][$key].":/content"
            )->upload(
                $_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$key]
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception, showing the following error message when I try to upload a :

```
Client error: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Documents/Screen%20Shot%202022-10-30%20at%204.03.44%20PM.png:/content` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response
```

In the Azure API Permissions, I have granted the `Files.Read.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, and `User.Read` permissions. However, when I check the access token in https://jwt.ms/, I just see `"scp": "User.Read"`.

So it looks like my access token might not have the correct permissions, but I can see that I do have permissions to read and write files when I look at the API Permissions page in Azure.

How can I further debug this issue and find a solution to upload files from my server to OneDrive?

Comment: Isn't the scope parameter missing in your 'form_params'? I mean, it looks you are not asking for the "Files.ReadWrite.All" scope in the code above. So the token returned does not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nikolay's comment, I added a `scope` parameter to `form_params` and that fixed it.

I also changed the `grant_type` to `client_credentials`, and removed the username/password authorization.

```
    $user_token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
    $user_accessToken = $user_token->access_token;
```